# webpage title icon that keeps changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, title

I have 10 different images that I want to use as icons on my webpage title.I want each I icon to show for 1 second then switch to the next(like a slideshow). How can I do that. I know I should use javascript but I am not very good at it. But I really need this. Any help much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you mean the favicon - you'll need an animated GIF, see the duplicate. It isn't supported by a lot of browsers though. Off topic -  I would consider changing that silly Gravatar to something else. It's completely unnecessary, and offensive to a great number of people here.

Comment: There seems to be another way as well: http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/